# ConcurrentModificationException while using PriorityQueue

Tags: java, collections

I am using a for-each loop to iterate over a `PriorityQueue` and trying to poll it.

Why am I getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`?. Where am I modifying '`concurrently`' as the Exception name implies? Is assigning itself a modification as it internally uses poll()? Please explain.

> Snippet:

```
String[] sa = {">ff<", "> f<", ">f <", ">FF<"};
        //This code demonstrates that white spaces come before capital letters and 
        //capital letters come before the small letters in natural ordering
        PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        for (String str : sa) {
            pq.offer(str);
        }
        System.out.println(pq);
        for (String str : pq) {
            System.out.print(pq.poll() + " ");
        }
}
```

**Edit:**

As I understand from the explanations given below, each poll() method invocation causes the size of the `PriorityQueue` object to change. So, it makes sense to throw an exception while iterating and trying to poll(`varying the size constantly`). Hence the `pq` object is throwing an exception which is a misnomer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's not a misnomer- you are modifying while (concurrently with) iterating over it. "Concurrent" is a bit of a trigger word in programming but it's a normal English word which just means "at the same time"; whether that is in a different Thread or in the same Thread.

Comment: @Erwon Bolwidt. Thank you. I meant it in the context of threads. I will modify it. But is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?.

Because you are modifying a collection while iterating it.

> Where am I modifying 'concurrently' as the Exception name implies?

You are modifying it when you call `poll()`.  That call *removes* the first element of the queue (if there is one) ... and that is a modification to the queue.

> Is assigning itself a modification as it internally uses poll()?
>
> I am talking about for(String str: pq) line. There each element in the pq is being assigned to the str in one iteration right?

No.  It is not using `poll` internally.

It wouldn't make sense!  The `for` loop creates an Iterator and then calls `hasNext()` and `next()` on it.  But those calls are not allowed to modify the underlying collection.  The `poll` method does modify the underlying collection, so it *clearly* can't be used.  (But feel free to find / read the source code for PriorityQueue.)

---

I should note that when I (and the other answers) are talking about iterating, we are referring to the explicit or implicit use of an Iterator object provided by the `Collection` object.  And when you apply an "enhanced" `for` loop to a collection, you are implicitly creating and using an `Iterator`.

By contrast, @Shekhar's solution is NOT using an `Iterator` so there is no issue with CME's in his code.

> One thing still I don't get is why does for-each create an Iterator?

It does so because the Java Language Specification *says* it does!  This is *how* Java implements "for each" iteration for this kind of object.  You can read all about it in the spec - [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

(But note that no iterator is created when you apply an "enhanced" `for` loop to a array.)

Comment: I am talking about for(String str: pq) line. There each element in the pq is being assigned to the str in one iteration right?

Comment: I understand that poll() is modifying collection. One thing still I don't get is why does for-each create an Iterator? As I know of loops, they are capable of iteration. Excuse me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 4):

You're modifying it (`pq.poll()`) concurrently with the iteration (`for (String str : pq)`).

Despite what the name suggests, concurrent here doesn't mean concurrency in the multithreading sense. It just means "at the same time as." Specifically, if you modify most of the collection classes during the time that you iterate over them — as you do in this case — they'll throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. Not *all* of them do, mind you; in particular, the ones designed for multithreaded access don't. But most of the basic ones, such as `PriorityQueue`, do.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate like bellow:

```
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(pq.poll() + " ");
    }
```

then you wont get ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: I don't think so.Can you explain why?

Comment: @Octopus - you "don't think so" what?  This code won't give a CME.  Like Shekhar says.

Comment: because in while loop it is not iterating over underline collection it's just checking collection has more element or not so thats why it want give CME.

Answer (score 1):

From ConcurrentModificationException javadocs

*Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.*

Comment: What is fail-fast iterator?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for CME is, "you are modifying the collection(either removing,adding or updating) at the same time while iterating a in a loop. In your case, you are calling poll() method that is updating the collection. Please refer the source code of PriorityQueue.java for poll() method"

So your best bet here is to use Iterator while traversing collection. This will prevent from CME

Comment: Ermm ... he's already using an iterator!  And that is the root of his problem here.

Comment: The given code is only using for loops, not Iterator object

Comment: It is time you read the JLS!!  A "for each" loop on an `Iterable` creates and uses an Iterator under the covers.

Comment: See my updated answer for a link to the relevant section of the JLS.

Comment: When we use enhanced for loop, behind the scene we are using Iterable object. You are right. But when we use enhanced for loop it will throw this exception. So i told to use standard approach. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you use an Iterator explicitly, it will also throw the exception.  Try it and see.